# How do I configure DHCP client to use the "routers" option as well as the "rfc3442-classless-static-routes" option?

Tags: 15.04, dhcp, dhclient

The DHCP server on my network sends the following options:

```
option routers n.n.n.n;
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes ...;
```

But the DHCP server is (incorrectly?) configured to send the actual default gateway in the "option routers" message and not in the "option rfc3442" message.

This worked in version 14.10, but unfortunately since version 15.04 the rfc3442-classless-static-routes option over-rides the routers option. This has been reported as a bug here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/1465183

but it's the result of a bugfix described here:
http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-dhcp-commits/2014-August/000272.html

What's the cleanest way to use the default gateway specified in the "option routers" message even if there's an "option rfc3442..." message present?

Presumably something in /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/ ?